# Yii2 Cant call the action Function?

Tags: routes, yii2, url-routing, yii2-basic-app

I am facing a very odd error here. I am trying to call an action in my controller but it leads to 404 page.

I have module called admin and it has controller called Product. The code is as follows

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{


public function actionIndex()
{
    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    if($session->has('user'))
    {
        $this->layout="admin-layout";
        $numbers= UserPurchasedNumber::find()->all();
        return $this->render('index',["number"=>$numbers]);
    }
    else
    {
         return $this->redirect(['admin/default/login']);
    }
}

public function actionPurchaseLocalNumber() //Dont get called
{
    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    if($session->has('user'))
    {
        $this->layout="admin-layout";
        return $this->render('addlocalnumber');
    }
    else
    {
         return $this->redirect(['admin/default/login']);
    }
}


}
```

in my view i am trying to call the url as follows

```
<div style="text-align: center; padding:15px">
                <a href="<?php echo Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('admin/product/purchaselocalnumber'); ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Purchase Numbers</a>
            </div>
```

But it is throwing 404.

Infact when i change the action name to

> Purchase

only and call it from view file it works?

Whats the problem??

Comment: Try `admin/product/purchase-local-number`.

Comment: it worked but it is like that? In Y1.x this problem never occurs

Comment: In Yii 2 camelCase in actions/controllers names resolves to more friendly names - `camelCase` becomes `camel-case` which looks nicer in URLs than `camelCase` like in Yii 1.1.

Comment: See https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-controllers#controller-class-naming

Answer (score 0):

the problem is located in you url :

admin/product/purchaselocalnumber

your action is named :

actionPurchaseLocalNumber

so you url must be like : **admin/product/purchase-local-number**